# App engine only running php files from root folder

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, yaml

I have activated Google app engine which will handle my php and html pages.
In my root folder, all php files work without problems. For testing purposes, all php pages just have one line of code.

```
<?php echo 1234;?>
```

If i place these files to root of the app, everything works without problems. If I place files inside folder, for example folder 'dynamic', nothing works. I get "Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."

my yaml file looks like this

```
runtime: php81
env: standard
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: /index\.html
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index\.html
  - url: /(.+\.php)$
    script: \1
  - url: /static/(.*)
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*
  - url: .*/(.*)
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*
  - url: .*
    script: auto
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
service_account: ganizani@merchvids-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I tried checked if the static pages are working and confirmed that everything works without problems there. I have checked error logs but they do not contain useful information. They just show that a 500 error occurred. I do not know how else to diagnose the issue. As I said, when i move the php files to root, everything works. Move them to folder in root, everything breaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
runtime: php81
env: standard
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: /index\.html
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index\.html
  - url: /(.+\.(php|html))$
    script: \1
  - url: /static/(.*)
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*
  - url: .*/(.*\.(php|html))$
    script: \1
  - url: .*
    script: auto
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
service_account: *-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

With this revised configuration, PHP files contained inside folders ought to be appropriately routed, and the 500 problem ought to vanish. In this arrangement, PHP and HTML files in subdirectories are both found using the regular expression `(.+.(php\|html))$`.

After making these changes, be sure to deploy your new `app.yaml` file to your Google App Engine project.